# How to post form login using jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

i want to login in [here](https://www.desco.org.bd/ebill/login.php)
[image]
source code

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>:: Dhaka Electric Supply Company Limited (DESCO)::</TITLE>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<META http-equiv=Pragma content=no-cache>
<META http-equiv=imagetoolbar content=no>
<META content="Home Page of  Dhaka Electric Supply Company Limited" name=description>
<META content="MSHTML 6.00.2900.2180" name=GENERATOR>
<style type="text/css">
    img{
        border:0px;
    }   
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax-dynamic-content.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax-tooltip.js"></script>   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ajax-tooltip.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ajax-tooltip-demo.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
<LINK media=all href="css/global.css" type=text/css rel=stylesheet>


</HEAD> 
<BODY>
<DIV id=over style="DISPLAY: none"></DIV>
<DIV class=baselayout>
<DIV class=pagetopshadow></DIV>
<DIV class=basebg>
<DIV class=pageleft></DIV>
<DIV class=pagecenter>
<DIV id=Header>
</DIV>
<DIV id=Menu>
</DIV>
<DIV id=HomeContent>
<DIV class=right>
<DIV class=homeintro>

<div style="padding-top: 0px;">
<script> 
function checkLogin()
 { if( document.login.username.value == '') 
  { 
  alert( 'Please enter  your account number' );
   return false; 
   }return true;
   }
   alert('Payments through VISA and Master Card are stopped by DBBL. only DBBL Nexus card is allowed.');
    </script>

        <form NAME='login' METHOD='POST' ACTION='authentication.php'>

          <table width="350" height="181"cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' style="border:#e5e5e5 0px solid; BACKGROUND: url(css/images/top9.png) no-repeat left top;" align="center">
          <tr> <td rowspan="6" style="padding-left:15px;"><img src="css/images/groupperms.gif" width="50" height="50"><td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" height="50"></td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
              <td nowrap><span class="textcolor1">Account No. </span></td>
              <td><input type='text' name='username' style="border:#cacaca 2px solid; color:#000099;" value=''></td></tr>

            <tr>
            <td> <a class="uiTooltip" href="#" onMouseOver="ajax_showTooltip(window.event,'tooltip/help.html',this);return false" onMouseOut="ajax_hideTooltip()">Help</a></td>
            <td><input name="login" type='submit' value='Login' style="width:80px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; color:#FFFFFF; border:#000000 2px solid; cursor:pointer; background-color: #1b4585;"  border="0" align="right" title="Login"  onClick="return checkLogin();"/></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        </form>
<table width="630" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td width="80"></td>
    <td><img src="images/right_3.gif"/></td>
    <td><span class="textcolor"><strong><a href='https://www.desco.org.bd/index.php?page=internet-bill-payment' target="_blank" class="uiTooltip">Before, use this facility/services please read instructions...</a></strong></span></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<p align="center" class="textcolor"><strong><a href='https://www.desco.org.bd' class="uiTooltip">Back Home</a></strong></p>
<table align="center" width="135" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" title="Click to Verify - This site chose VeriSign SSL for secure e-commerce and confidential communications.">
<tr>
<td width="135" align="center" valign="top"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://seal.verisign.com/getseal?host_name=www.desco.org.bd&amp;size=S&amp;use_flash=YES&amp;use_transparent=YES&amp;lang=en"></script><br />
<a href="http://www.verisign.com/ssl-certificate/" target="_blank"  style="color:#000000; text-decoration:none; font:bold 7px verdana,sans-serif; letter-spacing:.5px; text-align:center; margin:0px; padding:0px;">ABOUT SSL CERTIFICATES</a></td>
</tr>
</table>


</div>
<div align="center" style="padding-top:10px;">



<CENTER><B>
    Total Visits:  1</B></CENTER>   
</div>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class=pageright></DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=pagebotshadow>
<DIV  id=Footer>Copyright © 2010 Dhaka Electric Supply Company Ltd. All rights reserved.</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

basically below code is the form

```
<form NAME='login' METHOD='POST' ACTION='authentication.php'>

      <table width="350" height="181"cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' style="border:#e5e5e5 0px solid; BACKGROUND: url(css/images/top9.png) no-repeat left top;" align="center">
      <tr> <td rowspan="6" style="padding-left:15px;"><img src="css/images/groupperms.gif" width="50" height="50"><td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" height="50"></td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
          <td nowrap><span class="textcolor1">Account No. </span></td>
          <td><input type='text' name='username' style="border:#cacaca 2px solid; color:#000099;" value=''></td></tr>

        <tr>
        <td> <a class="uiTooltip" href="#" onMouseOver="ajax_showTooltip(window.event,'tooltip/help.html',this);return false" onMouseOut="ajax_hideTooltip()">Help</a></td>
        <td><input name="login" type='submit' value='Login' style="width:80px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; color:#FFFFFF; border:#000000 2px solid; cursor:pointer; background-color: #1b4585;"  border="0" align="right" title="Login"  onClick="return checkLogin();"/></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    </form>
```

[image]

i am trying this

```
package jsouptest;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class JsouptTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://www.desco.org.bd/ebill/login.php")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.desco.org.bd/ebill/login.php")
                .data("cookieexists", "false")
                .data("username", "32007702")
                .data("login", "Login")
                .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                .post();
        System.out.println(document);

    }

}
```

but im getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:439)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
    at jsouptest.JsouptTest.main(JsouptTest.java:12)
```

am is missing something? how to fix it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The URL that are you using in order to do the POST request is wrong, simply because when you have to do a specific request to a form you should use the web page that is present in the form tag, in this case "authentication.php".

So the code will be:

```
    package jsouptest;

    import org.jsoup.Connection;
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

    public class JsouptTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

           Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://www.desco.org.bd/ebill/login.php")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

           Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.desco.org.bd/ebill/authentication.php")
            .data("cookieexists", "false")
            .data("username", "32007702")
            .data("login", "Login")
            .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
            .post();
           System.out.println(document);

       }

    }
```

This one correctly retrieves the web page that you want.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that I didn't send the viewstate, eventvalidation, viewstategenerator values.

To get these values you have to first send a GET request to the login form page.
In my instance this was a default.aspx page.

Then you have to extract those values and put them into variables. Also of course you need the form login and password field ids, the submit button's id, among other things. For a list of all those variable that are sent, login manually and use chrome dev tools (inspect elements) to look at the network tab for a POST request. Inside it should show the username and password you submitted. There you will see other variables that are sent.

[network tab in dev tools example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIbhm.png)

Next, send a POST request including all those variables, save the cookies from the response into a variable, and you can then use that to go to another page.

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.FormElement;


public class get_example {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //===================================
    Connection.Response response2 = Jsoup.connect("yourloginpage")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

    Document responseDocument = response2.parse();

    Element eventValidation = responseDocument.select("input[name=__EVENTVALIDATION]").first();
    Element viewState = responseDocument.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATE]").first();
    Element viewStateGen = responseDocument.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR]").first();



    Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("yourloginpage")
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .data("ctl00$plnMain$txtLogin", "username")
            .data("ctl00$plnMain$txtPassword", "password")
            .data("ctl00$plnMain$Submit1", "Log In")
            .data("ctl00$ucCopyright$hdnPrivacyStatement", "Privacy Statement")
            .data("ctl00$ucCopyright$hdnTermsOfUse", "Terms of Use")
            .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewState.attr("value"))
            .data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", viewStateGen.attr("value"))
            .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation.attr("value"))
            .execute();


    Map<String, String> cookies = response.cookies();


    Document homePage = Jsoup.connect("anotherpage")
            .cookies(cookies)
            .get();


    System.out.println(homePage.body().html());

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it consists in three steps:

1. Get cookies from login form page;
2. Post credentials to login form `action=` URL, renew cookies;
3. The user will be redirected to index page. Don't parse here, just send `Response` to the final target URL.
4. Parse when you reach the final page.

The cookies should be renewed in every step, sometimes add entries, and sometimes you must clear it and reset. Be sure to check the network transmission with Internet Explorer/Chrome/Firefox Dev tool (<kbd>F12</kbd>), in the Network panel, `cookies` part.