# Java how to manipulate a html text element with dynamic generated name?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsoup

I want to manipulate or set text in a `input type="text"` tag on a website. But this input has a dynamic generated name on every load.

How to get and manipulate this element in java?

Here is an example

```
<form method="POST" name="sform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="text-align: center;">
<input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" style="position: absolute; left: -5000px">
<input type="checkbox" name="honeypot" style="position: absolute; left: -5000px">
<center>
<input type="text" name="VHqnx63SwDau2nuNOOFRM2MCJ5sJawbpHv" class="form-control" value="" 
                    placeholder="Type Text here" style="width: 448px; text-align: center;">
```

The name "VHqnx63SwDau2nuNOOFRM2MCJ5sJawbpHv" is on every new loading the website something else.

I found no really helpful posts to this problem.

Should I maybe use something like jsoup?

Comment: Where would this data come from? Hot did you get this enourmous name?

Comment: @Pablo its not my site. it is a site on the internet. I dont know how they implemented it. i want to make a fill in autonomous instead of fill in manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should definitely use Jsoup.

With Jsoup, it should be as simple as this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
System.out.println(doc.select("form[name=sform] > center > input").first());
```

This gets the first input element from the HTML which is a child of a `centre` element which is in a `form` element.

Which prints:

```
<input type="text" name="VHqnx63SwDau2nuNOOFRM2MCJ5sJawbpHv" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Type Text here" style="width: 448px; text-align: center;">
```

Jsoup also offers lots of other cool stuff like directly getting or setting attributes, and lots more. So you could do:

```
Element e = doc.select("form[name=sform] > center > input").first();
e.attr("value", "Something");
System.out.println(e);
```

Which would print:

```
<input type="text" name="VHqnx63SwDau2nuNOOFRM2MCJ5sJawbpHv" class="form-control" value="Something" placeholder="Type Text here" style="width: 448px; text-align: center;">
```

With the value set to "Something".

Comment: Thanks @JonasCz i will give a try and get back

Comment: @HaShLo, Let me know if you have any problem, and I'll try to help.

Comment: Hi @JonasCz it worked very well , how to submit this form now after add an attribute in it ?

Comment: @HaShLo, You need to manually get the data from the form and then post it to the server, check this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320498/how-to-post-form-login-using-jsoup . You need to get the URL where the form should be submitted to from the HTML, and then add all the input values from the form as name / value pairs, and post it.

Comment: thanks again. I tried it, but it not work with the solution of the other post.

Comment: i dont know if you will notified, because of the code i made a new answer. please look down, thanks