# How to edit live HTML using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I tried to implement the solution provided here:

[Java how to manipulate a html text element with dynamic generated name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459452/java-how-to-manipulate-a-html-text-element-with-dynamic-generated-name)

It worked but when I did inspect element the HTML was as is, no change was made to the page. It didn't give any error.

This is what I tried:

```
        gotoPage("https://www.demo.com/in/");
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.demo.com/in/").get();
        System.out.println("Before "+doc.select("#top-menu > div > div.nav-logo > a").first());
        Element e = doc.select("#top-menu > div > div.nav-logo > a").first();
        e.attr("href", "https://demo-custom-page.net/demo/test-jsoup.html");
        System.out.println("After "+doc.select("#top-menu > div > div.nav-logo > a").first());
        Thread.sleep(120000);   // inspect element and if html changed or not
```

I am working on Windows 7, Java, Selenium, Maven

Answer (score 0):

You can't. When you edit HTML using Jsoup the only thing modified is the document you store in `doc` variable. You won't see these changes in web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do that if you create threads for "atomic" things. Some solution is to use File and  FileUtils.writeStringToFile() to write in file.