# JSOUP: set form data

Tags: java, forms, jsoup, wordnet

I am creating a JAVA program that uses JSOUP. This is what I have in mind:

I want to use WordNet (http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn).
I there is a basic form there where a user can input a string. It checks if the string is a word in the English dictionary. 
When you submit the form the URL changes. I get this URL using. Then I check for a certain h3 tag that appears only if it is not a word.

My issue is able to fill the form and submit it using JSOUP, and getting the URL of where the submission takes me.

Here is the form

```
<form method="get" action="webwn" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="f">
Word to search for: 
<input type="text" name="s" maxlength="500">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Search WordNet">
<input type="hidden" name="o2" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="o0" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="o8" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="o1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="o7" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="o5" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="o9" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="o6" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="o3" value="">    
<input type="hidden" name="o4" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="h" value="">
</form>
```

I'm not sure what to do. This is the only part I am stuck on. 
I tried this so far but it does not do anything

```
public static String getUrl(String search) throws IOException{
        String url = "http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .data("S", search)
                .data("o2", "")
                .data("o0", "1")
                .data("o8", "1")
                .data("o1", "1")
                .data("o7", "")
                .data("o5", "")
                .data("o9", "")
                .data("o6", "")
                .data("o3", "")
                .data("o4", "")
                .data("h", "")
                .post();
        String newURL = doc.location().toString();
        System.out.println(newURL);
        return (newURL);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just search what you want by manipulating the url's endpoint:

`http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=` and concatenating what you want to search to it.

if the word you're searching for was `"bill"` then

```
/*
 * returns url of search term using jsoup
 */
public static String getUrl(String search) throws IOException{
    String url = "http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url + search).get();
    String newURL = doc.location().toString();
    System.out.println(newURL);
    return (newURL);
}
```

then if you just wanted to test if a word was a word you could do this

```
/*
 * returns true if is a word
 */
public static boolean isWord(String search) throws IOException{

    String url = "http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=";
    String notAWord = "Your search did not return any results.";

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url + search).get();
    String searchH3 = doc.select("h3").text();

    return searchH3.contains(notAWord) ? false : true;

}
```

if you want to make the post request however you could do it by using `Connection.Response` to get the response of your `post`. You just need to have `import org.jsoup.Connection` as an import to use the Connection API.

```
public static String getUrl(String search) throws IOException{

    Connection.Response wordForm = Jsoup.connect("http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

    String url = "http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .data("s", search)
            .data("o2", "")
            .data("o0", "1")
            .data("o8", "1")
            .data("o1", "1")
            .data("o7", "")
            .data("o5", "")
            .data("o9", "")
            .data("o6", "")
            .data("o3", "")
            .data("o4", "")
            .data("h", "")
            .cookies(wordForm.cookies())
            .post();

    System.out.println(doc);

    String newURL = doc.location().toString();
    return (newURL);
}
```

A similar example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320498/how-to-post-form-login-using-jsoup)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I did not know that I could have done that.

Comment: I updated the answer on how to resolve your current case if you were curious.