# Unable to fetch the text from the div, Although i getting that content in response

Tags: java, jsoup

Unable to fetch the text from the div... Using below code, Not sure whats the issue

```
try {
    connection =  new URL("https://en-gb.facebook.com/Aeysunnna/videos/265359950651320/")
        .openConnection();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream(),"UTF-8");
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");
    content = scanner.next();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("error");
}

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
Thread.sleep(10000);
Elements elements = doc.select("div._1t6k");
System.out.println(elements.text());
```

Comment: It seems that you are using non-default APIs (JSoup). If so always state that in your question and use the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because your *Java browser* is **not logged in** to Facebook. If you're not logged in you will see nothing except the login page. Thus you can not read the content of the `div`, you are currently at the starting page.

Try printing the whole content you're getting and check whether it is actually the starting page.

---

You find an in-depth explanation here: [Finding a word in a web page using java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45905710/2411243)

As shown there you will probably not find an *easy fix* for this issue.

---

Also note that scraping Facebook without using their own API **violates** their **Terms of Service**.

Comment: I am able to see that div in the content after the HTML parse, But still not able to fetch the text of that div.

Comment: So the document `doc` contains the `div` with all its content when you print it? But `doc.select` doesn't select it? Please show the relevant content by **editing** your question. Your selector is probably incorrect or something like that.

Comment: Yes doc contains that div but when i am using Elements elements = doc.select("div._1t6k"); its returning the elements  size zero

Comment: I am getting this div aswell after HTML parse <div class="_1t6k"><span class="fcg">7 M Views</span></div>