# How to get the html code from webview and put it in textview?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

Hi guys Im very frustrate searching this question on Internet.
I want to get the html code from WEBVIEW and then put it in textview
I dont want to use jsoup for some reason
My only hope is javascript Interface

Please give me a working code to study

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use jsoup but in the end you should use a htlm or javascript parser

Comment: I want to get the html code of a page on website. But I cant get the html code from my targe page because The site have login page, you know what I mean?

Comment: YOU ARE GOING TO HAVE TO POST THE **URL** before ***anybody*** can help you.  :)

Comment: you can login and handle this with login cookie in jsoup or if download file to storage you link to your store then parse.

Answer (score 0):

First Login and get login cookie then parse website

```
Connection.Response response= Jsoup.connect("https://loginpage")
                .data("user",user,"pass",pass)
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();
       Map<String,String> cookie=response.cookies();
      
       Document document=Jsoup.connect("https://loggedwebsite")
            .cookies(response.cookies())
            .get();
```

Check also this:
[How to post form login using jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320498/how-to-post-form-login-using-jsoup)

Comment: I don't believe that works for the logon page of most of the (numerous) web-site / social-media / e-mail / video-sharing platforms out today on the Internet.