# Basic JSoup form Submission

Tags: java, jsoup

My form submission does not seem to work, I tried JAunt it was able to submit so when using JSoup I don't understand why it returns `404`.

```java
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://crawlertest284814019.wordpress.com/contact/#contact-form-7")
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
    .data("name", "nameeee")
    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
    .execute();
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried with:

- url `https://crawlertest284814019.wordpress.com/contact/`
- data `"name", "nameeee"` produces 404 status
- data `"g7-name", "nameeee"` no issue but no submission
- data `"Name", "nameeee"` no issue but no submission
- data with Map<String, String> no issue but no submission

Comment: Your form seems to also contain some `<input type="hidden" ...>` elements which probably 
should also be sent.

Comment: @Pshemo you are absolutely correct! I did not notice those fields. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Pshemo, the code is ok however the data passed is lacking. Those hidden fields contain information required in order for the submission to be valid. In the case of this question the hidden fields are:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="4d18e01372">
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/contact/">
<input type="hidden" name="contact-form-id" value="7">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="grunion-contact-form">
<input type="hidden" name="contact-form-hash" value="07cbf543790375cf26022ad8826a8dbb8787beae">
```

So aside from the required fields make sure to submit the hidden once as well.

```java
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://crawlertest284814019.wordpress.com/contact/#contact-form-7")
    .data("g7-name", "Super sName")
    .data("_wpnonce", "4d18e01372")
    .data("_wp_http_referer", "/contact/")
    .data("action", "grunion-contact-form")
    .data("contact-form-id", "7")
    .data("contact-form-hash", "07cbf543790375cf26022ad8826a8dbb8787beae")
    .post();
```

Answer (score 0):

Status code 404 is a client-side error, there is something wrong with your input.
Refer below link it will solve your problem.
[How to post form login using jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320498/how-to-post-form-login-using-jsoup)

Comment: trying the actual `name=` value of the field which in this case is `g7-name` does not seem to do any different. no error but no submission entry as well.